# mvc controller in constructor does not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

hello this my controller class 
and I did a constructor but constructor does not working (debug skips
thank you

```
  public class CrewController : Controller
{
    public CrewController()
    {

        string d = "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: please tag which language you are using.

Comment: the scope of the d is inside the contructor only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public class CrewController : Controller
{
    string d ="";
    public CrewController()
    {

        d = "test";
    }
}
```